# can I have an UpdatePanel with three control IDs?

Tags: asp.net

I have an Update panel with several objects in there. And I also have 3 buttons. Upon pressing which i want my the content of my update panel change.

My question is can I have 3 control IDs for the same update panel?

Comment: Are your buttons inside the update panel or outside the update panel?

Comment: They are located outside

Comment: OK, then can you try the code in my answer?

Comment: I actually have a triger. But the thing is the triger bond to only one button and i have 3 buttons each of which is in charge of displaying the separate objects inside the UpdatePanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have several controls in an update panel. If your buttons are outside the update panel you need to define triggers for each of your buttons in the updatel. Such as:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server">

<!-- Some contents -->

    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTest1" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTest2" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTest3" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: yes I know. But can it be like `<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTest1" ControlID="btnTest2" ControlID="btnTest3"  EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>`

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. Wait a minute I will try it